# Codeigniter does not redirect properly in remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, uri

I need a help here.

I want to ask why my CI doesn’t redirect properly in remote server?
Everything in my localhost runs without any problem.

For example :

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    function index() {
        //bla bla bla
        redirect('dashboard','refresh');
    }
 }
```

After I login successfully, I get the url: http://www.test.com/%20//www.test.com/dashboard
instead of: http://www.test.com/dashboard

This is a little silly problem and I have googled everywhere but no answer related, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to inspect the actually sent headers (with `wget -S` or Firebug, etc.). What it does is probably send a `headers("Refresh: 0; url=' //www.test.com/dashboard'");` header, or has a space right after the scheme `http:` prefix. Show us the `redirect()` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, okay, looked it up. This is the `redirect()` implementation from CodeIgniter (1.7.1):

```
             case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
```

Not pretty, but shouldn't cause the problem you described. Somehow a space still slipped in. I suspect it's a non printing Unicode space variant, and your browser later translates it into a normal space. -- It might also be the `$uri=site_url($uri)` call mentioned in that very help function, but did not look that up. Might be a site misconfig then.

The alternative is just trying the normal `location` redirect.

```
    redirect('dashboard');
```

Comment: woahhhhh, you're so awesome dude!!! You just saved my hours of life!
Thanks a lot!